# Does the Wallet Griefing Attack still Exists?

Tags: vulnerability

I read about Wallet Griefing attack at the following link:

```
[Ethereum Griefing Wallets][1]
```

'send' is checked but contract uses throw. The code is given below:

```
for (uint i=0; i<investors.length; i++) {
  if (investors[i].invested == min_investment) {
    // Refund, and check for failure. 
    // This code looks benign but will lock the entire contract
    // if attacked by a griefing wallet.

    if (!(investors[i].address.send(investors[i].dividendAmount))) 
      { 
        throw;
      }
    investors[i] = newInvestor;
  }
}
```

Can this attack still occur by replacing throw with revert?

Somebody please guide me?
Zulfi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this vulnerability is still a fairly common mistake I see. I actually just wrote an article about it a couple weeks ago: https://medium.com/consensys-diligence/provable-fair-ransom-1547ba894d0.

Whether it's `throw`, `require`, or `revert` doesn't matter. The point is that if one recipient can cause the transaction to revert, no one can get paid.